# How to search recursively within several levels of embedded tar tgz files?

Tags: files, grep, tar, recursive, archive

Can somebody help me to figure out a command to find a file recursively that is embedded in a tgz file which is within another tgz files recursively:

`MainFile.tgz` → `SubFile1.tgz` → `SubFile2.tgz` → `SubFile3.tgz` → `abc.txt`

My goal is to be able to list `abc.txt` without extracting `MainFile.tgz` nor `SubFileX.tgz`.

The command below is only listing the first level of files (i.e. `SubFile.tgz`); therefore the grep command cannot find `abc.txt` in the list:

```
tar tvf MainFile.tgz | grep abc
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract them, but you don't need to store them on the disk :

```
tar -xOf MainFile.tgz SubFile1.tgz | tar -xO SubFile2.tgz | tar -xO SubFile3.tgz | tar -x abc.txt
```

The `-O` flags sets output to stdout and without `-f` `tar` will accept archive data from stdin.